# Ninject Binding By Parameter Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I use ASP .NET MVC and Ninject. I need conditional binding for parameter name. How can I do this?

```
private readonly ITemplateProvider _msgTemplate;
private readonly ITemplateProvider _mailTemplate;

public OrderLineManager(ITemplateProvider msgTemplate,ITemplateProvider mailTemplate)
{
    _msgTemplate = msgTemplate;
    _mailTemplate = mailTemplate;
}

//ninject kernel , 
//i need for msgTample MessageTemplateProvider
//i need for mailTemplate MailTemplateProvider
_kernel.Bind<ITemplateProvider>()
    .To<MessageTemplateProvider>()
    .When(request => request.Target.Member.Name.Equals("msgTemplate"));

_kernel.Bind<ITemplateProvider>()
    .To<MailTemplateProvider>()
    .When(request => request.Target.Member.Name.Equals("mailTemplate"));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
_kernel.Bind<ITemplateProvider>().To<MessageTemplateProvider>().When(a => a.Target.Name == "msgTemplate");
_kernel.Bind<ITemplateProvider>().To<MailTemplateProvider>().When(a => a.Target.Name == "mailTemplate");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
.when(a => a.Parameters.Single(b => b.Name == "parametername"))
```

I think this doesn't work with older versions of Ninject though.